# how to change the onclick attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a online shopping and this code

```
<button onclick="('productID','productCount')">buy</button>
```

In this the product ID is fixed but product Count is variable and I need users to set this product Count using a input value.

```
<input class="productCount" value="variabel number" />
```

How do I write this code with jQuery ?!!

Tnx for your Answer

Comment: As your are using jQuery, Don't use inline click handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JQuery you can use [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to match sets of elements in a document. So, `$("#productCount")` will return the element with id "productCount" and `val()` will return its value.

```js
$("#btnBuy").click(
  function() {
    alert($("#productCount").val());
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="productCount" value="variabel number" />
<button id="btnBuy">buy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
 <button data-id="productID" class="buy">buy</button>
 <input name="productCount" class="productCount" value="variabel number" />
```

js

```
$('.buy').on('click',function(){
   var productID = $(this).attr('data-id'),
       productCount = $(this).next('.productCount').val();
       //function to do stuf with variables
});
```

Comment: why do you use delegated events? elements are already in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Add id to the elements to retrieve the value and trigger the click event.

```
<button id="button_buy">buy</button>
<input class="productCount" id="productCount" value="variable number" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var productCount = $('#productCount').val();
    $('#button_buy').click(function(){
        ('productID','productCount')
    });
});
</script>
```